# Finding the arithmetic mean of a list of positive numbers

Tags: java, loops, mean, negative-number

I have created a program that will allow users to input the amount of numbers they wish to calculate the arithmetic mean. The program works fine, however I am trying to stop the program from accepting negative numbers. 
I have tried adding a while loop as shown below, however this isn't doing anything and I'm unsure as to why.

```
Scanner inputLine = new Scanner(System.in);

int numbers, start, sum=0, armean;
int array[] = new int[50];

System.out.println("program to find the arithmetic mean (average) of a list of positive numbers  ");
System.out.println("=======================");
System.out.println();
System.out.print("How many numbers do you want to Enter ? ");
numbers = inputLine.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter " +numbers+ " Numbers : "); 
while (numbers < 0){
    System.out.println("Incorrect number entered");
    System.out.print("Enter " +numbers+ " Numbers : ");
    numbers = inputLine.nextInt();
}

for(start=0; start<numbers; start++) {
    array[start] = inputLine.nextInt();
    sum = sum + array[start];
}

armean = sum/numbers;
System.out.print("Arithmetic Mean = " +armean);
```

Comment: What would you expect that to do? Think about the value of `numbers` when you enter the while loop.

Comment: while you are at it, why do you loop over numbers instead of the length of your array?

Comment: That `while` only avoids setting `numbers` to a negative value, it does not stop user from inserting negative values into `sum`. You should check for negative values before doing `sum = sum + array[start];`, something like `while(array[start]<0) array[start] = inputLine.nextInt();` before the `sum` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop is at the wrong position in the code.
Put it in here:

```
for(start=0; start<numbers; start++) {
    int number;
    do {
      number = inputLine.nextInt();
    } while (number < 0);
    array[start] = number;
    sum = sum + array[start];
}
```

Also you do not need the array at all (in fact in will cause errors if the user enters more than 50 numbers)

```
for(start=0; start<numbers; start++) {
    int number;
    do {
      number = inputLine.nextInt();
    } while (number < 0);
    sum = sum + number;
}
```

If you really want to keep the array initialize it with `numbers`:

```
int array[] = new int[numbers];
```

Comment: Ahhh I see, the penny has dropped, if I'm honest, I am new to using arrays so beginners mistake. I have used a while loop as mentioned above for other scenarios in the past hence why I thought that logic would work. Thanks for your clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

Work through the logic with these scenarios:

- You enter a couple of negative numbers followed by some positive numbers
- You enter a positive number, a couple of negative numbers, then a couple of positive numbers.

You should see the problem when you do this. (Problems -- there are a couple.) Be sure to look at the value of each variable when you get to each line.

Answer (score 0):

You loop over your array, but this has not been influenced by your while loop at all, you have influenced numbers instead.

This should work:

```
for(start=0; start<numbers; start++)
 { 
    array[start] = inputLine.nextInt();
    if (!array[start]<0)  {
    sum = sum + array[start];
  }
}
```

Comment: Using `if` is not correct. If the user inputs a negative value this code will just skip it and ask for the next value, so the final result won't be correct. Also, there's no reason to do `! <` when you can use `>`.

Comment: looping over numbers is not correct in the first place, the end of the forloop has to be changed anyhow